# Sharedpreferences error index out of bounds

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to save an Arraylist in my with the method SharedPreferences. The problem i get is that my index is out of bounds but i don't see why:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    data = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor0 = data.edit();
    editor0.putInt("shareddifficulty", difficulty);
    editor0.putInt("sharedmoves", moves);
    editor0.putInt("sharedpicture",resource);
    editor0.putInt("ID_size", ID.size());

    for(int i=0;i<ID.size();i++){
        editor0.remove("ID_"+i);
        editor0.putInt("ID_" + i, ID.get(i));  
    }
    editor0.commit();               
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    data = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
    difficulty = data.getInt("shareddifficulty", 0);
    moves = data.getInt("sharedmoves",0);
    int listsize = data.getInt("ID_size", 0);
    resource = data.getInt("sharedpicture", 0);
    for(int i=0; i < listsize;i++){
         ID.set(i,data.getInt("ID_" + i,0));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        crops.set(ID.get(i),cropsshuffle.get((ID.get(i))));
    }

}
```

The cropslist and ID list are of the same size. Because it's quite important to know how the arraylists look like i'm going to show the codes for crops and the code for ID:

crops:

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);

    //Cropping the images and making a ID list that coincide with the cropped images.

     divideImages(bmp);
```

with

```
private void divideImages(Bitmap bmp) {

    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    float w_ratio = (float) w/width;
    int scaledwidth = (int) (bmp.getWidth()*w_ratio);
    int scaledheight = (int) (bmp.getHeight()*w_ratio);
    Bitmap scaledbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,scaledwidth,scaledheight,true);

    switch(difficulty){
        case 0:
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    if(i==2 && j==2){
                        Bitmap cropimage  = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledwidth/3,scaledheight/3,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        crops.add(cropimage);
                        cropimage = null;
                    }
                   else{
                        int startx =  (int) ((scaledwidth*j)/3);
                        int starty =  (int) ((scaledheight*i)/3);
                        Bitmap croppimage  = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledbmp,startx,starty,scaledwidth/3,scaledheight/3);
                        crops.add(croppimage);
                        croppimage = null;
                    }
                }
                grd.setNumColumns(3);
            }
            break;                                
        case 1:
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                    if(i==3 && j==3){
                        Bitmap croppimage  = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledwidth/4,scaledheight/4,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        crops.add(croppimage);
                        croppimage = null;
                    }
                    else{
                        int startx = (int) ((scaledwidth*j)/4);
                        int starty = (int) ((scaledheight*i)/4);
                        Bitmap croppimage  = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledbmp,startx,starty,scaledwidth/4,scaledheight/4);
                        crops.add(croppimage);
                        croppimage = null;
                    }
                }
                grd.setNumColumns(4);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    if(i==4 && j==4){
                        Bitmap croppimage  = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledwidth/5,scaledheight/5,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        crops.add(croppimage);
                        croppimage = null;
                    }
                    else{
                        int startx = (int) ((scaledwidth*j)/5);
                        int starty = (int) ((scaledheight*i)/5);
                        Bitmap croppimage  = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledbmp,startx,starty,scaledwidth/5,scaledheight/5);
                        crops.add(croppimage);
                        croppimage = null;
                    }
                }
                grd.setNumColumns(5);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and for ID list:

```
private void getID(){
    for(int i=0;i<crops.size();i++){
        ID.add(i);
    }
}
```

In my gridview i have an onitemclicklistener which changes the positions if we swap the tiles of crops and ID.

Comment: You should post your arrays initialization and population as well, with the provided code we can't be sure what's going on

Comment: It's a bit hard to do that, because the function is quite long, the only thing you need to know is that crops is a arraylist of bitmaps and ID's is a list with integers and has the same size as crops.

Comment: i can put the code on as wel if you really want to?

Comment: Did you try to trace your code with the debugger to see what exactly gets saved into SharedPrefs and what exactly do you retrieve?

Comment: yes i did :), did'n't see what went wrong though

Comment: Which line is causing that index out of bounds? And what is the index exactly? It is mentioned in the logcat. Please give all info. In onPause or onResume?

Comment: `ID.set(i,data.getInt("ID_" + i,0));` will cause you trouble as array ID will be empty at onResume so having no elements. You could instead better .add() them.

Comment: @KeesTil yes, post your code as well

Comment: OMG guys i solved it, the code was ok, but because i was debugging with SharedPreferences it saved the bugs as well. The only thing i needed to do is delete the app and reinstall it xD.

Answer (score 1):

I made a library to ease this kind of task, just include my lib:

```
    compile 'com.cesarferreira.quickutils:library:2.2.1'
```

Init it:

```
QuickUtils.init(context);
```

then you save/read/delete easily anywhere you want:

```
QuickUtils.prefs.save(key, value);
QuickUtils.prefs.getInt(key, defaultValue);
QuickUtils.prefs.remove(key);
```

All the documentation [here](https://github.com/cesarferreira/AndroidQuickUtils)

Answer (score -2):

From the above code I cannot tell you where the error is.

But the `IndexOutofBoundsException` occurs when you try to access an item in your `Array`, that is not inside your Array.

**Example:**

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
myArray[10] = "test";
```

This resolves into `IndexOutofBoundsException`, since your array is only from **0-9**.

Based on the above simple example of the error, try to found out what is going wrong in your code. Otherwise post a more specific code, since as you can see, your error revolves around your `Array`.